# Context Menu Not Firing on Right Click

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the following `ListBox`. This works great and when I *left* click on the `TextBlock` it opens the recent file. However, when I right click the context menu does not open, instead it acts like a left click and the command `LoadSelectedFileCommand` fires, opening the recent document. Below is the `ListBox` XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, IsAsync=True, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuListBoxItem}" 
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
         Grid.Row="6" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type RecentObjects:RecentFile}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsPinned}"
                             Style="{StaticResource imageCheckBox}" 
                   ToolTip="{Binding IsPinned, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVariableStringConverter}}" 
                             DataAccess:DocumentCheckBox.IsCheckedOnData="{DynamicResource Pinned}"
                             DataAccess:DocumentCheckBox.IsCheckedOffData="{DynamicResource UnPinned}"
                             AttachedCommand:CommandBehavior.Event="Click"
                             AttachedCommand:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MahAppsControls:MetroContentControl}}, Path=DataContext.UpdateRecentFilesCommand}" >
                </CheckBox>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" 
                              Style="{StaticResource MenuTextBlock}" 
                              ToolTip="{Binding FullFileName}" 
                              AttachedCommand:CommandBehavior.Event="MouseDown" 
                              AttachedCommand:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MahAppsControls:MetroContentControl}}, Path=DataContext.LoadSelectedFileCommand}"
                              AttachedCommand:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter="{Binding FullFileName}">
                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Open Study" />
                            <MenuItem Header="Open Containing Folder" />
                            <MenuItem Header="Remove From List" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
</ListBox>
```

My question is **how can I get the context menu to fire on the right click and the command to open on the left click?**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the LoadSelectedFileCommand to run when the left mouse button is clicked you should use the [UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttondown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.